# how to solve SSRS Formatting issue?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Currently the data in field is coming like this **9646.88** and my requirement is

***Remove decimal places and add comma for thousands e.g. 9,646***

```
=IIF((RTRIM(Fields!COMPANY_NAME.Value))="VACANT","",Fields!BASE_RENT_PM.Value)
```

*Please help, I am a newbie in SSRS.*

Comment: `9646.88` coming with which data type? String(varchar)?

Comment: yes.....................

Comment: @DeepakJain The answer you accepted will return 9,647 instead of 9,646 as being mentioned in your question. Please see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675488/how-to-solve-ssrs-formatting-issue/37677008#answer-37677008)

Answer (score 1):

Go to Properties pane when you select the textbox.

Then put this on **Format** property

`#,0;(#,0)`

Comment: It will display same value. `9646.88`

Answer (score 1):

Using Common Functions such as Text and Conversion functions shown in Expression window will give you the desired result.

For e.g,

```
Format(Int(9646.88), "#,###") // try "#,##0" which returns 0 if less than 1
```

where `Int(9646.88)` returns the integer portion of the number `9646` and `Format(9646,"#,###")` returns a string formatted according to instructions contained in a format String expression `"#,###"` which is a thousand seperator. Thus, it will give you **"9,646"**.

So, in your case, try this,

```
=IIF(RTRIM(Fields!COMPANY_NAME.Value)="VACANT", "", Format(Int(Fields!BASE_RENT_PM.Value),"#,###"))
```

> Note:
>
> `Format(9646.88, "#,###")` will return a rounded result `9,647` and
>
> `Format("VACANT", "#,###")` returns just `"#,###"`,
>
> none of which may not be your desired result.

Comment: i am using this =IIF((RTRIM(Fields!COMPANY_NAME.Value))="VACANT",Nothing,IIF(isNothing(Fields!BASE_RENT_PM.Value),"9",Format(Int(Fields!BASE_RENT_PM.Value), "#,###"))) but when the value in null the #error is coming need help

Comment: try inspecting `Not( isNothing(Fields!COMPANY_NAME.Value) )`

Answer (score 0):

Have your Tried this?

```
=FORMAT(IIF((RTRIM(Fields!COMPANY_NAME.Value))="VACANT","",Fields!BASE_RENT_PM.Value),"#,###")
```

Should solve your issue.
Kind Regards

Comment: If data comes with varchar data type. then it will show `#,###`

Answer (score 0):

To add comma for thousands, you need to change your expression.

If you need output as `9,646` then try below.

```
 =IIF(RTRIM(Fields!COMPANY_NAME.Value)="VACANT","",Format(Convert.ToInt32(Int(Fields!BASE_RENT_PM.Value),"#,0;(#,0)")))
```

***OR***

```
=IIF(RTRIM(Fields!COMPANY_NAME.Value)="VACANT","",Format(CInt(Int(Fields!BASE_RENT_PM.Value),"#,0;(#,0)")))
```

***Updated Answer:***

As you want to handle null values as well I would suggest below way to achieve your goal.

Set Textbox visibility with below expression.

```
=IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!BA‌​‌​‌​SE_RENT_PM.Value),True,False)
```

*So if null value is there then it will show blank in the ssrs report.*

Comment: i am using this =IIF((RTRIM(Fields!COMPANY_NAME.Value))="VACANT",Nothing,IIF(isNothing(Fields!BA‌​SE_RENT_PM.Value),"9",Format(Int(Fields!BASE_RENT_PM.Value), "#,###"))) but when the value in null the #error is coming need help

Comment: which value is null?

Comment: actually when it is null in DB (column value) it should return blank in SSRS otherwise value with commas with no decimal

Comment: In detail summary :- i am getting numeric value from store proc but in some cases it can be null so my requirement is if it is not null then it should display with 1000 separator comma and null value should show blank in the ssrs report

Comment: okay now tell me, which expression you have used currently? my answer one or Sythr's answer one or your own?

Comment: =IIF((RTRIM(Fields!COMPANY_NAME.Value))="VACANT",Nothing,IIF(isNothing(Fields!BA‌​‌​SE_RENT_PM.Value),"9",Format(Int(Fields!BASE_RENT_PM.Value), "#,###")))

Comment: seems you have not used Sythr's answered expression and then also you marked his answer as correct answer? :-| I have answer for you but please mark correct answer which helps you. Not random one. As it can be shown by many users. So please support to stack overflow in terms for correct answer. Thanks.

Comment: please check my and updated answer let me know if helps or not. thanks